# Windows 7 Control Panel View - Vertical List Alphabetically

Tags: windows-7, control-panel

I would like to list the control panel items vertically instead of horizontallly in icon view. How can I do this?

Comment: View by large icons and 'Pinch' the screen would be one way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

God Mode give me what I wanted and more. So from this [Url](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/GodMode-Windows-7-How-to,9345.html)

Step 1: Right click.

Step 2: Click create folder.

Step 3: Name your sparkly, new folder this, "GodMode.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}" and press enter.

Step 4: Blink as the folder changes form to look like the control panel.